# How to create custom shapes using css3 in div?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve following shape using CSS3 without using canvas, can anyone help me to achieve this following shape?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transform:skew()` CSS property

Here is a code example

```css
.rect {
  width:100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.skew {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background:#33FF99;
  transform:skew(0deg,-27deg);
}

.r1, .r2, .s1{
  position:absolute;
}

.r1{
  top:60px;
  left:0;
}

.r2 {
  top:10px;
  left:200px;
}

.s1{
  top:35px;
  left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect r1"></div>
<div class="skew s1"></div>
<div class="rect r2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.fbid,Its perfect shape.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*CSS* 2D transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) with [skewY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew) :

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  width:200px; height:50px;
  background:green;
  margin:0 100px;
  transform-origin:100% 0;
  transform:skewY(-30deg);
}
div:before, div:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:50%; height:100%;
  transform:skewY(30deg);
  background:red;
}
div:before{
  right:100%;
  transform-origin:100% 0;
}
div:after{
  left:100%;
  transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*Note that you need to add the vendor prefixes according to the browsers you need to support. More info on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)*

Answer (score 2):

`transform: skewY(Ndeg)` to get the angle effect, then either margins or `transform: translateY(Npx)` to move the divs vertically. Working example:

```css
.red,
.green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: lime;
}

.first {
  /*margin-top:56px;*/
  transform: translateY(56px)
}

.second {
  transform: skewY(150deg) translateY(28px);
  /*transform: skewY(150deg);
  margin-top:28px;*/
}

.second span {
  transform: skewY(30deg);
  display: inline-block;
}

.third {}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="red first"><span>div</span></div>
  <div class="green second"><span>div</span></div>
  <div class="red third"><span>div</span></div>
</div>
```